# How to ORDER BY DateTime in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm looking to execute the following query:

```
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select( 'e' )
            ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
            ->setMaxResults( $limit )
            ->setFirstResult( $offset )
            ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC');

        $events = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Where

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\EventRepository")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateStart;

...
}
```

But the order by doesn't work.
My results are not displayed by date start.

I'm looking to retrieve the 20 first events happening from the soonest to the latest

How can I do this ?

Thanks

EDIT:

Following the previous answer, I'm updating my query.
unfortunatey I still can't have it working.
Please help

```
     $qb->select( 'e' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
        ->Where( 
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->between('e.dateStart', ':from', ':to')
            )
        )
        ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC')
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit );
```

Thanks

EDIT 2:
It seems moving orderBy did make a difference. I don't have any error as of right now. The script is running fine with orderBy BUT it is NOT ORDERED by datetime at all !

In my results I can't see anything that would make me think it has been ordered based on any given property, definitively not datetime !

How is that possible ?

The Datetime field looks like something like that in the DB:
    2014-05-24 19:30:00

When I var Dump the queries that comes out of the previous query, here is what I have for the datetie field:

```
 ["dateStart"]=> string(8) "DateTime"
```

Does that mean it's really a string for doctrine and that's why it is not sorted by datetime ?

Thanks

Comment: precision=0, scale=0, are they required when field type is datetime ? strange.. remove these two as they are for number types, and then try.. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you are right, its only for decimal :)

Comment: I still can't have it working :( any help on this

Comment: $qb->add('orderBy', 'p.created DESC');

Comment: this is the same as what I'm doing, doesn't work :/
Correct me if I'm wrong but ->add('orderBy', 'e.dateStart') is the same as ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC') ?

Comment: Is that the _exact_ query? If so: you don't need the `andX()` there because you only have 1 expression. If not, _show us the exact query_. We need to know if there are things like JOIN clauses, or if you're using the Doctrine Paginator, etc...

Comment: This query works without the orderBy. When I add the OrderBy, it just fails. Doctrine 2 doesn't seem be able to sort by a datetime field

Comment: Doctrine is perfectly capable of ordering results by a datetime property. If the order comes out wrong, you are doing something you're not telling us...

Comment: @MilesM.: If the order just fails with the orderBy, then what's the error message? Do you see anything in the logs?The only thing that strikes me (apart from the spare `andX`, which Jasper mentioned), is that the DB column is named differently than the entity property.

Comment: "it just fails" is not helpful. What is the error message?

Comment: thanks for your help guys. I've updated my question yesterday, it isn't failing anymore, it simply doesn't order anything at all. I am very confused with that ..

Comment: Please provide a sample of the un-ordered result and which displays the `e.dateStart`; and could you identify the `actual dbms data type` of that field (not what you see in your ORM)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Database

You should check the table structure *in the database*:

What type of column is `date_start`?
It should be `DATETIME` (in MySQL, other vendors may vary).
But I suspect it is some form of string, like `VARCHAR` (or `CHAR`, `TEXT`, etc).

When this is the case, the result *is ordered*, but not in the way you expect it. This is because different types are ordered differently by the database.

#### CLI tool

Doctrine comes with a console tool that's able to validate your mappings and check if the database is consistent with them: `doctrine orm:validate-schema`.

If it reports inconsistencies with the database, use `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` to have it display the queries it would perform to update the database (it will assume the mappings are the source of truth).

Comment: Thank You Jasper. here are my annotations for this field. IT IS DATETIME.
`/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="datetime", nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateStart;`

Comment: @Miles M. I'm not talking about the mapping metadata (annotations), but about the _actual database_. (It's not Doctrine performs the query, thus ordering the result, it just generates the query. It's the _database_ that executes the query.)

Answer (score 6):

your Query would be like :

```
    $qb->select( 'e' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
        ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC');
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults(20);
```

you have to respect the order of query builder parameters i hope that will help.

Comment: ho didn't know there was a specific order, where can I learn what's the correct order ? I've been going through the D2 doc many many times but never seen that

Comment: This is actually not working after several tests.

I have updated my answer to paste my actual query.

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html - This article is useful for you. See point 13.2.5. The Expr

Comment: which parameters are you talking about @TahaMetal ? The order of method calls doesn't count here.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give me the result of:

```
$qb->select( 'e' )
    ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit )
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC');

die($qb->getQuery()->getSql());
```

One possible thougth:
Is your getter for the property $dateStart is well declared ? It should be:

```
public function getDateStart()
{
    return $this->dateStart;
}
```

Comment: the getter has nothing to do with DQL.

Comment: Which getters?
this is what happen when I echo SQL:

`SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.name AS name1, e0_.description AS description2, e0_.link AS link3, e0_.social_media_link AS social_media_link4, e0_.booking_link AS booking_link5, e0_.price AS price6, e0_.currency AS currency7, e0_.picture AS picture8, e0_.date_created AS date_created9, e0_.date_start AS date_start10, e0_.date_end AS date_end11, e0_.popularity AS popularity12, e0_.confirmed AS confirmed13, e0_.user_id AS user_id14, e0_.admin_id AS admin_id15, e0_.place_id AS place_id16 FROM event e0_ ORDER BY e0_.date_start ASC LIMIT 200 OFFSET 0`

Comment: with the exact query you suggested (simplier)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can rewrite your code like this

```
 $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select( 'e' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit )
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->orderBy('date(e.dateStart) ASC');//this is the trick that works for me

    $events = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Fails for me: I am getting `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 191: Error: Expected known function, got 'date'` (Doctrine 2.8.x).

Answer (score 0):

The order of the query parameter matters. In your case, the query should be:

```
    $events = $qb->select( 'e' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
        ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Not entirely sure what you mean by '20 first events happening from the soonest to the latest', but that should you give you the latest set of events. To change the order change 'DESC' to 'ASC'.