# Doctrine sort only by date

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have query builder:

```
$lastEvents = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Entity')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e')
            ->where('e.to_trash = false')
            ->orderBy('e.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(100);
```

and  *.orm.yml:

```
created_at:
            type: datetime
```

Sorting is working, but only by date (not a time), like this:

01.02.2015 05:02:05
01.02.2015 03:02:02
**01.02.2015 09:02:13**
**01.02.2015 09:02:01**
29.01.2015 11:01:52
29.01.2015 11:01:22

Must be:

**01.02.2015 09:02:13**
**01.02.2015 09:02:01**
01.02.2015 05:02:05
01.02.2015 03:02:02
29.01.2015 11:01:52
29.01.2015 11:01:22

Tell me how to make it sorting by time?

Comment: What is the actual column type in database? Can you check that?

Comment: Type in database is **datetime**

Comment: sounds odd that its not working as you seem to have things right.  have a look at this post, it might shed some light. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997077/how-to-order-by-datetime-in-doctrine-2

Comment: Can you show your runnable query? (from debug mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my stupid mistake:

I use twig like:

```
date|date("d.m.Y h:m:s")
```

but must (24 time format):

```
date|date("d.m.Y H:i:s")
```